# ESRI ArcGIS Javascript : Polygon from JSON not working

Tags: javascript, json, arcgis, esri, esri-javascript-api

If you reference the image, JSON string, and code snippets below, it outlines the code, console output and expected behavior of trying to draw a polygon (or really any geometry/graphic) using the ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API. Not sure what is going on....help please!

JSON String:

{"geometry":{"rings":[[[-91.89013671874848,38.03029444608522],[-91.653930664061,38.00865683368494],[-91.64843749999851,38.00432854459864],[-91.5935058593735,37.93070854451552],[-91.577026367186,37.88303274722063],[-91.577026367186,37.79192956603227],[-91.631958007811,37.73982010276601],[-91.70886230468598,37.73547599031287],[-91.763793945311,37.76587942393493],[-91.85168457031098,37.85701474874939],[-91.88464355468598,37.9956711998967],[-91.89013671874848,38.03029444608522]]],"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}},"symbol":{"color":[0,0,0,64],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":1,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"}}

Code to add Shape to Map:

```
    function createFromJSON(JSONText){
      console.log("In Create Function");
      dojo.disconnect(handle);

      var jsontext = JSON.parse(JSONText);
      var polygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(jsontext);
      console.log("Here is the polygon object:");
      console.log(polygon);
      console.log("Now drawing polygon");
       map.graphics.add(new Graphic(polygon, new SimpleFillSymbol()));
      console.log("Polygon should be there");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: "Not working" is not a great description. Also, consider adding the relevant code to the actual post instead of just a screenshot. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON string shown in the image is for `Graphic` object and not a geometry. As you can see it contains `geometry` & `symbol`, If you pass it to Graphic it will work.

```
map.graphics.add(new Graphic(jsontext));
```

Or if you just want the polygon then your code should be something like this.

```
var polygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(jsontext.geometry);
```

Also, dont combine legacy and AMD style together.

Answer (score 0):

As T Kambi said, your string is for graphic not geometry, but I'm going to show some ideas in converting between json and esriGeometry.

You can convert *json* to `esri.Geometry`, using any of these ways:

- `JsonUtils` (`esri/geometry/jsonUtils`) or
- `esri.geometry.fromJson` method.

Here is the code:

**METHOD ONE (USING `JsonUtils`)**

```
require(
    ["esri/map", "esri/geometry/jsonUtils", "esri/config", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (Map, JsonUtils, esriConfig) {

    var jsonGeometry = {"x":10,"y":20,"spatialReference":{"wkid":3857}};

    //Note: you should not use JsonUtils.fromJson(JSON.stringify(jsonGeometry))
    var geometry = JsonUtils.fromJson(jsonGeometry); 
    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(firstGeometry);
});
```

**METHOD TWO (Using `geometry.fromJson` method)**

```
var jsonGeometry = {"x":10,"y":20,"spatialReference":{"wkid":3857}};
var geometry = esri.geometry.fromJson(jsonGeometry);
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry);
```